# CSS for input attribute selector

Tags: css

i am trying to make css for input box in html. i have little knowledge of css can any one please solve my small query. i want different-different style and size for all input box. want no change in html code.

```
<div class="field">
<div class="input">
<input name="post_rehub_offers[rehub_multioffer_group][0][multioffer_url]" class="vp-input input-large" value="" type="text">
</div>
</div>

<div class="field">
<div class="input">
<input name="post_rehub_offers[rehub_multioffer_group][0][multioffer_name]" class="vp-input input-large" value="" type="text">
</div>
</div>

<div class="field">
<div class="input">
<input name="post_rehub_offers[rehub_multioffer_group][0][multioffer_desc]" class="vp-input input-large" value="" type="text">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You forgot to mention how you want to style the inputs and what you have already tried to do so. Please make sure to read [ask] and edit your question.

Comment: You can style input elements by their tag name, by adding class(es), by their ID, name, or any combination. What styling do you want applied to each and what styles should be common vs. unique? Eg do you want the font, borders, margin and padding all the same but the widths to be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to change the html.

You can use a *wildcard* in an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

According to MDN

> [attr*=value] Represents an element with an attribute name of attr the
>   value of which contains at least one occurrence of string "value" as
>   substring.

Since your inputs have distinct name properties we can target those.

The names of your inputs are

1. `post_rehub_offers[rehub_multioffer_group][0][multioffer_url]`
2. `post_rehub_offers[rehub_multioffer_group][0][multioffer_name]`
3. `post_rehub_offers[rehub_multioffer_group][0][multioffer_desc]`

So we can target

1. `input[name*="url"]`
2. `input[name*="name"]`
3. `input[name*="desc"]`

And apply whatever styles you want to them like so:

```css
input[name*="url"] {background:red}
input[name*="name"] {background:green}
input[name*="desc"] {background:blue}
```

```html
<div class="field">
<div class="input">
<input name="post_rehub_offers[rehub_multioffer_group][0][multioffer_url]" class="vp-input input-large" value="" type="text">
</div>
</div>

<div class="field">
<div class="input">
<input name="post_rehub_offers[rehub_multioffer_group][0][multioffer_name]" class="vp-input input-large" value="" type="text">
</div>
</div>

<div class="field">
<div class="input">
<input name="post_rehub_offers[rehub_multioffer_group][0][multioffer_desc]" class="vp-input input-large" value="" type="text">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a CSS referring the below example.

```
<html>
  <head>
      <style>
        input {
          width: 100%;
          box-sizing: border-box; }
     </style>
 </head>
</html>
```

Put this script in the `head` tag of `html`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.input-element-1{
   width:300px;
}
.input-element-2{
   width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
<div class="input1">
<input name="post_rehub_offers[rehub_multioffer_group][0][multioffer_url]" class="vp-input input-large input-element-1" value="" type="text">
</div>
</div>

<div class="field1">
<div class="input2">
<input name="post_rehub_offers[rehub_multioffer_group][0][multioffer_name]" class="vp-input input-large input-element-2" value="" type="text">
</div>
</div>
```